# Eclipse Color Theme: "Color Theme" not showing up

Tags: eclipse-plugin, color-scheme

I'm trying to change how I work so I don't get a headache after 8 hours of sitting at the computer so I want to play with colors in Eclipse to see if it helps.

I've heard praise of this Eclipse Color Theme plugin.

I install in via the Eclipse Marketplace, I drop a .xml file theme into the "dropins" directory in eclipse directory located on my hard drive, select window->prefrences->general->apperence->??? where is "Color Themes"? It's just not there!

Anyone know what could be the issue? I am running Eclipse Juno EE with one other plugin EGit.

Install manually? I've already reinstalled the Color Theme plugin twice now!

**[SOLUTION] I just found out the problem from the help of another post. I was not running as Administrator as my Program Files directory is protected. Answer: Always run Eclipse as Administrator or on a Linux system SUDO. My files were not installed due to the lack of privileges.**

Comment: I have same issue on MacOS using Oxygen Release (4.7.0). I installed Color Theme and some themes (i.e. Lunar) but on the list I can still se the three default themes.

Answer (score 2):

No, the right answer is to unzip eclipse at a location, where it can write, even without root/admin access. Do not put Eclipse into the "program files" folder.

Historically, eclipse has been designed to be able to modify itself in place, and you will be running into trouble every now and then, when your installation cannot do that and you didn't point it to a writable configuration area via eclipse.ini settings.

Answer (score 2):

Help->Install New Software->Add

Name: Color Theme

Location: http://eclipse-color-theme.github.com/update

After install this, will show the Option in the Menu.

Comment: It says no software site found at http://eclipse-color-theme.github.com/update

Comment: Just in case that the answer by user Robin is deleted, I provide the link update info they contributed. (In my opinion, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70952583/7733418 , with some eidting, is an answer and I credit it for this info.): https://eclipse-color-theme.github.io/update Let me know if I missed something which makes that link questionable.