# No more color theme in post Photon Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, colors, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, color-scheme

I am doing a new install on windows and have tried both 2018 versions and 2019-03 with java 8 through java 11 and there is no way to get the good ol' color theme installed.  It does not show up in marketplace or anywhere I search and I cannot just install the one in the marketplace from the market place website by dragging and dropping the link into eclipse (you can do this with older eclipse versions).

What is the alternative for getting new versions of eclipse to be usable and visually appealing?

I can install other plugins so it is not a rights issue like in this post [Eclipse Color Theme: "Color Theme" not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650258/eclipse-color-theme-color-theme-not-showing-up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Eclipse Color Theme 1.0.0" shows up for me in Marketplace inside Eclipse.

Alternatively, if you install "Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle" from the Marketplace (which you may or may not want), you can go to  **Preferences** -> **DevStyle** -> **Color Themes**
to import Eclipse Color Themes (XML).

But:
The last activity on the [Eclipse Color Theme Github](https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme) is from Sept 2016. Coloring of abstract classes for Java is broken in all themes, i believe because [this PR](https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme/pull/265) from Sept 2017 has not been merged. The [Eclipe Color Themes Website](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/) is broken in various ways for me in Firefox.

I checked for active forks on Github and didn't really find any yet. So for the time being, i sadly believe Eclipse Color Themes to be dead.

Anyway, the problem with abstract classes can be fixed for now by manually searching through the files in your Eclipse installation for the jar containing "eclipsecolortheme" , unzipping it, applying the PR linked above  to its contents and re-zipping it. Not pretty, but it works for now.